# sorting Vertices ClockWise

Tags: java, sorting

I am using This Algorithm To sort a list of Point ClockWise:

```
private List<Point2D> SortClockWise(List<Point2D> Points) {
    // First Calculate Center of Points
    double CenterX = 0;
    double CenterY = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i++) {
        CenterX += Points.get(i).getX();
        CenterY += Points.get(i).getY();
    }
    Point2D Center = new Point2D(CenterX / Points.size(), CenterY
            / Points.size());
    int n = Points.size();
    int k;
    for (int m = n; m >= 0; m--) {
        for (int i = 0; i < n - 1; i++) {
            k = i + 1;
            if (!less(Points.get(i), Points.get(k), Center)) {
                Point2D tmp = new Point2D();
                tmp = Points.get(i);
                Points.set(i, Points.get(k));
                Points.set(k, tmp);
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < Points.size(); i++) {
        mTempShape.add(Points.get(i));
    }
    return mTempShape;
}

private Boolean less(Point2D a, Point2D b, Point2D center) {
    if (a.getX() - center.getX() >= 0 && b.getX() - center.getX() < 0)
        return true;
    if (a.getX() - center.getX() < 0 && b.getX() - center.getX() >= 0)
        return false;
    if (a.getX() - center.getX() == 0 && b.getX() - center.getX() == 0) {
        if (a.getY() - center.getY() >= 0 || b.getY() - center.getY() >= 0)
            return (a.getY() > b.getY());
        return b.getY() > a.getY();
    }

    // compute the cross product of vectors (center -> a) x (center -> b)
    double det = (a.getX() - center.getX()) * (b.getY() - center.getY())
            - (b.getX() - center.getX()) * (a.getY() - center.getY());
    if (det < 0)
        return true;
    if (det > 0)
        return false;

    // points a and b are on the same line from the center
    // check which point is closer to the center
    double d1 = (a.getX() - center.getX()) * (a.getX() - center.getX())
            + (a.getY() - center.getY()) * (a.getY() - center.getY());
    double d2 = (b.getX() - center.getX()) * (b.getX() - center.getX())
            + (b.getY() - center.getY()) * (b.getY() - center.getY());
    return d1 > d2;
}
```

the problem is in some Cases Like this:

[image]

the algorithm gives me the BlackLine Drawn in the picture, But What i want to get is the Numbered Vertices In picture.

Comment: The black line looks like the correct expected behaviour to me. The points have been arranged clockwise in a circle (or at least as close to that as possible). The only way I see it being able to get what you want is if `Center` was a point somewhere in the middle of the 7-3-6 triangle. But that's only in this case - I think that for some other shapes no `Center` would work. So you probably want a completely different, more advanced algorithm that is aware of the role of the points as vertices of a shape, not just as locations. How is the shape currently represented?

Comment: Your center is located somewhere above point 3 (same x coordinate). This makes the sorting correct for that center.

Comment: yes the sorting is correct for this algorithm, But i want to Know How i can get the result that i want

Answer (score 1):

I would try an approach with splitting all into polygon first. Start with point 1, then you go though your vertex in your polygons until you reach a vertex that is shared. Then you have to change the polygon.
After all, if you only have points, without defining edges (implicit or explicit) you can only have a convex shape.